# Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to build a messenger in which the user should be able to login via their phone number. I set up my project in Firebase with the correct SHA-1 code and the correct packagename. But when I try to verify my phone number, I am getting this error:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.
> Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [App validation failed]

When I start my App from Android Studio, it is working fine. But when I upload the App to the Google Play Store, it is **not** working. What am I doing wrong?

I am starting the verification with this code:

```
startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(
                                Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()
                                ))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
```

I have this library for authentication:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
```

and this for the UI:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two SHA-1 keys, one you use in Android Studio and one that is used when you upload the app to the Store. You can check the SHA-1 key with the keytool command:

keytool -list -v -keystore **keystorename** -alias **alias** -storepass **storepass** -keypass **keypass**

Additionally, if you have enabled App Signing, Google will create a new certificate which will be used to sign the APK on the user's device.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

In the Release Management section, check App Signing. App Signing Certificate is the certificate sent to a user's device and Upload Certificate is the one you uploaded. Add the SHA-1 in the App Signing Certificate to your Firebase Project.

Comment: should I use the App signature certificate or the Uploadcertificate?

Comment: App signature certificate, upload certificate is the one you have uploaded and should be the same as the one in the Android Studio. After adding the key, it may take up several minutes for it to effect.